# Converting Flash Google Maps API to Javascript based in Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-maps

I was given an older program to work on, and it uses the Google Maps API for Flash. The application is built in Flash CS5 and cannot be converted to anything else but Flash (as it's a piece of a larger Flex application that takes Flash built swfs and loads them into a Flex built larger application) so I can't use a pure Javascript approach. And also I don't know any Javascript, I'm basically a pure Flash/Flex developer, heh.

Is there an "easy" way to convert the application from the Flash based API to the Javascript based API? I don't even know where to start, I'm just out of college, this is my first real big project, and I'm the only Flash dev

Otherwise I'm kind of stuck, because the API key expired, Google doesn't give out new keys and they aren't answering my request to renew the key. I was also looking into the MapQuest Flash API and converting it over to that, however, I'm not sure.

I also want to note I can't use a web view, as content needs to be shown on top, and the entire map needs to be integrated into the SWF, I should only be pulling data from the API and displaying it in Flash as a Flash element. I've used a web set up before and it would not be appropriate for my needs for this project.

Comment: Being that both actionscript and javascript share a hertiage it shouldn't be too difficult to switch the contexts.  Have you tried it yet?  Looking up each method the flash file calls and finding it's equivalent in the javascript api?

Comment: The content has to be displayed as a SWF because of the way the overarching larger application works, so I'm not sure if that would work.

Looking at the MapQuest API it's documentation is kind of... well it could be a lot better.

Comment: So wait.  You're not trying to do it in JavaScript? Or are you? If the Flash API from Google Maps is discontinued, you'll have to do it via JavaScript.  I know you can make JavaScript and ActionScript communicate between each other...

Comment: Yes, you can, but the only way I know of to display JS content is through a web view and I can't use that, as I need to display content above the web view. Alternately, I've been looking at the MapQuest Flash API, but most of the docs are for Flash Builder, however this particular application needs to be built in Flash specifically.

Comment: Converted the application to MapQuest's API (http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash). I was expecting a nightmare and I actually was very surprised at how smooth the transition went (as you can see by the time stamps). Didn't take me long at all.

Functionality is comparable, and it boiled down to just changing some function names to get the same functionality for simpler things, and then a bit of digging around and making everything work. 

Converting to MapQuest's Flash API seems like the proper answer to this problem (if someone else is having it).

Comment: you can answer and accept your own question for future arrivers at this one

Comment: Ok. I was going to yesterday, but I had to wait a day because I was a new user

Answer (score 1):

Converted the application to [MapQuest's API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash). I was expecting a nightmare and I actually was very surprised at how smooth the transition went (as you can see by the time stamps). Didn't take me long at all.

Functionality is comparable, and it boiled down to just changing some function names to get the same functionality for simpler things, and then a bit of digging around and making everything work.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to the duplicate question: [Embedding Google Maps in Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725861/embedding-google-maps-in-flash/15029139#15029139)  - I have implemented Bing, Google and MapQuest JavaScript maps and their elevation services in Flash - the full post (with code) was too long so it is here: http://pastebin.com/Jzq5E06F